# Double summation  with vectorized loops in Matlab

Tags: matlab, nested-loops, vectorization

I want to vectorize this double for loop because it is a bottleneck in my code. Since Matlab is a based-one indexing language I have to create an additional  term for M = 0.

R,r,lambda are constants

Slm(L,M),Clm(L,M) are matrices 70x70

Plm(L,M) is a matrix 70x71

Cl(L),Pl(L) are vectors 70x1

```
% function dU_r
  s1 = 0;
  for L = 2:70
     s1 = s1 + ((R/r)^L)*(L+1)*Pl(L)*Cl(L);
     for m = 1:L
        s1 = s1 + ((R/r)^L)*(L+1)*Plm(L,M)*(Clm(L,M)*...
cos(M*lambda) + Slm(L,M)*sin(M*lambda));
     end
  end

  dU_r = -(mu_p/(r^2))*s1;


  % function dU_phi

  s2=0;
  for L = 2:70
      s2 = s2 + ((R/r)^L))*Plm(L,1)*Cl(L);
          for m = 1:l
          s2 = s2 + ((R/r)^L)*(Plm(L,M+1)-M*tan(phi)*Plm(L,M))*...
  (Clm(L,M)*cos(M*lambda) + Slm(L,M)*sin(M*lambda));
          end;
  end;
  dU_phi = (mu_p/r)*s2;

  % function dU_lambda

  s3=0;
      for L=2:70
          for m=1:L
          s3 = s3 + ((R/r)^L)*M*Plm(L,M)*(Slm(L,M)*cos(M*lambda)...
              - Clm(L,M)*sin(M*lambda));
          end;
  dU_lambda = (mu_p/r)*s3;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following code may be a part of the solution (only partially vectorized), for a full vectorization you might want to look at `meshgrid`, `ndgrid`, `bsxfun` and/or `repmat`, I suppose.

```
s2     = 0;
L      = 2:70;
PlCl   = Pl.*Cl;
PlmClm = Plm.*Clm;
Rrl    = (R/r).^(L).*(L+1);
COS    = cos((1:70)*lambda);
SIN    = sin((1:70)*lambda);

for l=L
    M  = 1:l;
    s1 = sum(Rrl(l-1)*PlmClm(l,M).*(COS(M) + Slm(l,M).*SIN(M)));
    s2 = s2 + s1;
end;
s2 = s2 + sum(Rrl(L).*PlCl(L));
```

I haven't tried to run this code, so if it may complain about some dimensions. You should be able to figure that out (just some transposes here or there may do).

Just a note on the side: try to keep away from short variable names (and certainly ambiguous ones like `l` (that can be misread for a 1, a I or an l). Also, it might be easier to vectorize your code if you have actual (i.e. not coded) expressions to start with.

**edit**: applied corections suggested by gnovice

Comment: There are a couple of errors: 1) You need to index `Rrl` with `l-1` instead of `l` in the loop. 2) The coefficients and `Plm` that multiply the cosine terms also multiply the sine terms (note the parentheses in the question).

Comment: @gnovice: indeed, I overlooked those parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

For this particular situation, it will likely be more efficient for you to **not** fully vectorize your solution. [As Egon illustrates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181169/how-to-make-a-double-summation-in-matlab-with-vectorized-loops/6181810#6181810), it's possible to replace the inner loop through vectorization, but replacing the outer for loop as well could potentially *slow-down* your solution.

The reason? If you pay attention to how you index the matrices `Plm`, `Clm`, and `Slm` in your loop, you only ever use values from the [lower triangular parts](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/tril.html) of them. All of the values above the main diagonal are ignored. By *fully* vectorizing your solution, such that it uses matrix operations instead of a loop, you would end up performing unnecessary multiplications with the zeroed-out upper triangular portions of the matrices. This is one of those cases where a for loop may be a better option.

As such, here's a refined and corrected version of [Egon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181169/how-to-make-a-double-summation-in-matlab-with-vectorized-loops/6181810#6181810) that should be close to optimum with regard to the number of mathematical operations performed:

```
index = 2:70;
coeff = ((R/r).^index).*(index+1);
lambda = lambda.*(1:70).';  %'
cosVector = cos(lambda);
sinVector = sin(lambda);
s2 = coeff*(Pl(index).*Cl(index));
for L = index
  M = 1:L;
  s2 = s2 + coeff(L-1)*((Plm(L,M).*Clm(L,M))*cosVector(M) + ...
                        (Plm(L,M).*Slm(L,M))*sinVector(M));
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking like reference a solution given by Jan Simon [1](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/contributors/869888-jan-simon), I have written the following code for my problem

```
Rr = R/r;
RrL = Rr;  
cosLambda = cos((1:70)* lambda);
sinLambda = sin((1:70)* lambda);
u1 = uint8(1);
s1 = 0;
s2 = 0;
s3 = 0;
for j = uint8(2):uint8(70)
   RrL = RrL * Rr;
   q1 = RrL * (double(j) + 1);
   t1 = Pl(j) * datos.Cl(j);
   q2 = RrL;
   t2 = Plm(j,1) * Cl(j);
   t3 = 0;
   for m = u1:j
      t1 = t1 + Plm(j,m) * ...
         (Clm(j, m) * cosLambda(m) + ...
          Slm(j, m) * sinLambda(m));
        t2 = t2 + (Plm(j,m+1)-double(m)*tan_phi*Plm(j,m))*...
    (Clm(j,m)*cosLambda(m) + Slm(j,m)*sinLambda(m));
        t3 = t3 + double(m)*Plm(j,m)*(Slm(j,m)*cosLambda(m)...
                - Clm(j,m)*sinLambda(m));
     end
     s1 = s1 + q1 * t1;
     s2 = s2 + q2 * t2;
     s3 = s3 + q2 * t3;
  end
dU_r = -(mu_p/(r^2))*s1;
dU_phi = (mu_p/r)*s2;
dU_lambda = (mu_p/r)*s3
```